# Async in a foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web

I need to return value when every async method in a foreach has been ended.

How can I do that?

```
 return backupModel.find({}).exec().then(backups => {
        backupBuild = []
        backups.forEach((backup, i) => {
            userDB.getC(backup.id).then((user) =>{
                backupBuild[i].client=user
            })
        })
        return backupBuild,
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `Promise.all`:

```
return backupModel.find({}).exec().then(backups =>
    Promise.all(backups.map(backup => userDB.getC(backup.id)))
).then(backupBuild => console.log(backupBuild));
```

Comment: I need to assign to the client prop

Comment: So why don't you just map it at the end? `backupBuild.map(build => ({ client: build }))`

Answer (score 0):

I also have tried that : but  "Cannot set property 'client' of undefined"

```
return backupModel.find({}).exec().then(backups => {
    let backupBuild = [];
    let promises = [];
    backups.forEach((backup, i) => {
        promises.push(userDB.getCustomer(backup.idClient).then((user) =>{
            backupBuild[i]= backup;
            backupBuild[i].client= user;
        }))
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {return console.log(backupBuild)})
});
```